# Calling a custom dependency property defined in code-behind from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, code-behind

Is it possible to call a custom dependency property in the XAML of the element in which it is defined?

I mean, i have the following simple code for my mainWindow:

Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpecialToProperty =   DependencyProperty.Register("SpecialTo", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public double SpecialTo
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(SpecialToProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DoubleAnimation.ToProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i use that dependency property from the XAML partial code of the MainWindow class?

I mean something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnimationTEst.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"        
    SpecialTo=200>
```

I know it can be done using attached dependency properties, but is it the only way? Is it not possible to call a dependency property defined in the code-behind?

Thank you and sorry if the question is some kind of stupid, i'm just learning and trying to understand WPF.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer after I initially posted a wrong answer:
The problem really lies in circular dependencies if you use andreask's answer. I had to create a BaseClass for all windows:
**1) Create a new Window Base Class:**

```
public class BaseWindow : Window {
    public BaseWindow() { }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpecialToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SpecialTo", typeof(double), typeof(BaseWindow));

    public double SpecialTo {
        get {
            return (double)GetValue(SpecialToProperty);
        }
        set {
            SetValue(SpecialToProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This will be the new baseclass for all your windows.
**2) Modify your MainWindow xaml: 
(Change YOURNAMESPACE (2x) to your namespace name)**

```
<local:BaseWindow x:Class="YOURNAMESPACE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SpecialTo="100">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</local:BaseWindow>
```

3) **And you also need to modify your partial MainWindow.cs:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : BaseWindow {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

That worked for me, however, you will always need to use the extra xaml markup in your window declaration.

Comment: @Clemens Yea I do, it messaged me about it and I thought, since it is a complete different approach I'd rather create a new one. Please, correct me if I am wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question because there seems to be many ways to solve it correctly. I've upvoted the answers that best helped me, but i can't set any as the correct answer since all are correct.

So i'll just post a conclusion. If you think that i'm mistaken, please post a comment and i will correct my mind.

The main answer to my question is no, it is not possible to directly call a custom dependency property defined at code-behind from its "linked" XAML file. It is mandatory to instantiate the control in which the property is defined to call it.

To me, the best workarrounds to use a custom dependency property in XAML, defined in the code-behind are the posted by @Clemens and @Noel Widmer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28409930/1095785) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28409991/1095785)

Comment: Perhaps worth to mention that you could always **bind** to the Window's property in its own XAML, so there is no problem accessing the property value. Still not sure what exactly your mean with "call a custom dependency property". See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom dependency properties in XAML, but only if you instantiate the control in XAML. For example, take a customized `TextBox` element:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SpecialToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SpecialTo", typeof(double), typeof(MyTextBox));

    public double SpecialTo
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(SpecialToProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DoubleAnimation.ToProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can of course create an instance of `MyTextBox` in XAML and assign the `SpecialTo` property there:

```
<custom:MyTextBox SpecialTo="1.0" />
```

In your case, however, you're not instantiating the custom class `MainWindow`, but you create a new instance of class `Window`, and the `Window` class isn't aware of the custom dependency property (the `SpecialTo` property is not even available in `Window`, since you declared it within the `MainWindow` class).

For the dependency property to be recognized, you'd need to instantiate `MainWindow` directly:

```
<custom:MainWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"        
    SpecialTo=200>
```

However, this means you need to omit the `x:class` directive that used to combine XAML and codebehind of your window (otherwise you'd run into circular dependencies), and I'm not sure if this correctly initalizes your window...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Dependency properties are used to bind within XAML. If you want to bind to property defined in the code behind window you need to reference this window as XAML element, i.e. add tag for your main window x:Name="mainWindow", and next in the binding expression refer it as ElementName=mainWindow

Comment: like: <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, ElementName=mainWindow}"

Comment: Please don't add information to your answer in comments. [edit] your answer and put all the information there.